# Is it possible to represent set of rational numbers as the countable union of disjoint dense subsets?

Tags: general-topology, irrational-numbers

Let, Q is set of rational numbers with relative topology of natural topology on R. Is it possible to represent Q as the countable union of disjoint dense subsets?

P.S. According the famous book, "Counterexamples in topology" by Steen and Seebach, it is possible, (page 143. Definition of Roys Lattice space). But, I dont know the proof of this.

Comment: Try $x+D$, where $D$ are dyadic rationals, $x\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Yes, every LOTS is maximally resolvable (killing a mosquito with a shotgun..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there are various ways to do this.

In my opinion, the nicest is to consider restrictions on denominators - for example, let $B_k$ be the set of rational numbers whose lowest-terms representation has denominator a power of $k$ (with the convention that the lowest-terms representation of $0$ is $0\over 1$). Then:

- What can you say about each $B_k$ in terms of topology?
- How do the different $B_k$s relate? In particular, can you find an infinite set $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that for distinct $a,b\in X$ we have $B_a\cap B_b=\emptyset$ (which will then give you the partition you want)? *HINT: think about divisibility ...*

Comment: Its clear that every Bk is dense in Q, because for any efsilion>0, there exist a and b from Bk, such that, |a-b|<efsilion.

X must be such set: X={x from N: x is not a any power of any natural number.}
Clear that, union of Bk, when runs over the X, is Q.

Am I wright?

Comment: Also X is infinite, because it contains the set of prime numbers.